# docker-compose.yml for postgres encountering error

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am building a node, express, postgres web app,

> npm run dev

is working fine, but I am trying to register my app in a container using docker, I have 2 files Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml, both the contents listed below, and I am getting the following error.

Can someone please help me in fixing this error. Also, before I start my `docker-compose up` I ensured that there are no processes running in port 5432.

```
node_1      | (node:28) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
node_1      |     at Object._errnoException (util.js:992:11)
node_1      |     at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1014:20)
node_1      |     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1186:14)
node_1      | (node:28) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
node_1      | (node:28) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:8
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'
services:
  node:
    build: .
    command: npm run dev
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app/
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    links:
      - postgres
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: postgres://localhost:5432/dreamhouse
  postgres:
    image: postgres:9.6.2-alpine
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER:
      POSTGRES_DB: dreamhouse`
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your node server is trying to connect to postgres before it's ready to accept connections. Even though you used `depends_on` that only guarantee that the postgres server is running.

What you can do is use a script to make your node server to wait postgres to be ready before start. One way to do it is to use an bash script with [wait-for-it](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it). You could use something like:

> start_node.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

# This line says for the "wait-for-it" script to wait for localhost:5432 without timeout (-t 0)
./wait-for-it.sh localhost:5432 -t 0

# When "wait-for-it" is done, you can start your server
npm run dev
```

> docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  node:
    build: .
    command: ./start_node.sh
    ...
```